# UITableView contents are merging while scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uitextfield

I have dynamically created `UITableView` and trying to add `UILabel` and `UIButton` but when we open `UIViewController` it will come correctly and when i try to scroll entire things got messed up.

Am dynamically adding `UITextFields` and `UIButtons` based on the field id that i get from server.

here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Updates

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier;
    if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"VARCHAR"]){
        MyIdentifier = @"CharCell";

    }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"INTEGER"]){
        MyIdentifier = @"IntCell";
    }else{
        MyIdentifier = @"IntCell11";
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = Nil;

    cell= [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[dynamicCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

      }  
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        //cell.clipsToBounds=YES;
        if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"VARCHAR"]){
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getLabel:indexPath.row]];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getVarcharTextfield:indexPath.row:[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"INTEGER"]){
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getLabel:indexPath.row]];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getIntegerTextfield:indexPath.row:[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"SINGLESELECT"]){
            NSString *title=[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            NSLog(@"single runing");

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getSingleSelectLabel:indexPath.item :title]];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self addView:indexPath.row :[dynamicOptionFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] :[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"MULTISELECT"]){

            NSLog(@"runing");
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getLabel:indexPath.row]];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self addMultiSelectView:indexPath.row:[dynamicOptionFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]:[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        }




    return cell;

}
```

Please check the attached screenshots

while loading page [image]

When i scroll down it will become like this 
[image]

Now its not merging but when i scroll down i can see repeated cells.
For eg: i can see my first row multiple times (at end of scroll)

latest screenshots[image]

Comment: if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"INTEGER"]){
        MyIdentifier = @"IntCell";
    }else{
        MyIdentifier = @"IntCell";
    } once check these tow statements both are having same identifiers change them uniquely

Comment: A dirty way to resolve it will be `cell= [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];` But i say  it again it is a dirty way.

Comment: let me try your answers

Comment: @Bangalore post the latest screen shot

Comment: added new screenshot

Answer (score 1):

As you are adding same view again and again on tableviewcell, without verifying if it is already or not. Instead you can add once, and then play with hide/unhide the content depending on your condition.

There is another way: You can set tag to each of the subview and validate, if [cell viewWithTag:x] (x:Integer), is available, then remove it from view or use the same view.

```
//cell.clipsToBounds=YES;
        if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"VARCHAR"]){
// make check here before adding
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getLabel:indexPath.row]];
// make check here before adding
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getVarcharTextfield:indexPath.row:[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"INTEGER"]){
// make check here before adding            
[cell.contentView addSubview:[self getLabel:indexPath.row]];
// make check here before adding
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getIntegerTextfield:indexPath.row:[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

please Change the code as below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier;
    if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"VARCHAR"]){
        MyIdentifier = @"CharCell";

    }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"INTEGER"]){
        MyIdentifier = @"IntCell";
    }else{
        MyIdentifier = @"IntCell11";
    }


    cell= [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[dynamicCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }
     cell.textLabel.text = Nil;
           cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        //cell.clipsToBounds=YES;
        if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"VARCHAR"]){
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getLabel:indexPath.row]];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getVarcharTextfield:indexPath.row:[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"INTEGER"]){
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getLabel:indexPath.row]];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getIntegerTextfield:indexPath.row:[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"SINGLESELECT"]){
            NSString *title=[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            NSLog(@"single runing");

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getSingleSelectLabel:indexPath.item :title]];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self addView:indexPath.row :[dynamicOptionFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] :[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"MULTISELECT"]){

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getLabel:indexPath.row]];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self addMultiSelectView:indexPath.row:[dynamicOptionFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]:[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: but how it change order and how it merge each other?

Comment: @Bangalore  check the dynamicCell connection and init's

Comment: @Bangalore once try this aswell cell.clipsToBounds=YES;

Comment: @Bangalore your code was better before put cell= [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[dynamicCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }
rest of the code comes out of the if condition  if (cell == nil) without else

Comment: means? i didnt understand?